# Dynamic datalists and saving data into seperate tables from 1 html form

Tags: php

I am building an Inventory program for my internship. 
I have a datalist for categories that works with radio buttons. If user clicks yes, he can type a new categorie and if user clicks no he must select from the options in the datalist.

I would like to ask ur advice from ur experience on the following:

If the user clicks yes and types a new categorie, What is the best way for me to make it so that this value gets saved among the others in my datalist?

at the moment, I have been trying to use this code:

```
    <?php
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="admin";
$dbname="test";

$con=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to the database:' . mysql_error());

$mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO test (test, Naam, Adress, Land) 
         VALUES (' ', '$_POST[Naam value]','$_POST[Adress value]','$_POST[Land value]')";

mysql_query($sql);

$lastid=mysql_insert_id();

$sql2=INSERT INTO test2 (test, test2, NieuweCategorie, NameNew, Categorie)
              VALUES ($lastid, ' ', '$_POST[NieuweCategorie value]','$_POST[NameNew value]','$_POST[Categorie value]')";


mysql_query($sql2);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

For some reason I don't get any errors when using this, as a matter of fact I get a notice that my data was "succesfully Inserted" but yet I don't see my data being saved in my Database.

Hopefully this question isn't too broad and hopefully I've posted enough information to make clear what I want!

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: Side note: Stop using old and deprecated `mysql_*` functions and start using MySQLi/PDO prepared statement and variable/value binding.

Comment: This is so horrible: `'$_POST[NieuweCategorie value]'` it goes like this: `'" . $_POST['NieuweCategorie value'] . "'`

Comment: Where can i find and look into this new codes than Mr. Passerby? I have just recently began programming making everything i have off a html 5 webdesign for beginners book and the internet...

And are u implying that my use of old codes is making this not work for me or something?

Some clearer advice would be appreciated! ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. functions are not variables and only variables do have the `$` sign: `mysql_select_db();`
2. don't use deprecated `mysql_` functions, [look into the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), you have better functions like PDO and mysqli or mysqlnd as alternatives
3. [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php) and Code Injection is not something for PHP only, it can happen in all languages, google for security improvements regarding it
4. (should be the first advice) start with the basics. how to concat strings and variables, about the quotation and enclosing, something I cannot show often enough is the [Zend Code Style Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html)
5. once you mastered the basics, go on with objects. turning from procedural to object orientated improves php projects from all aspects by 1500%
6. do not try to implement everything at once, take one step after the other, PHP provides so many examples of code usage, try to understand each line of code instead of the whole thing
7. if you feel like mastering the advanced steps, you can go on with the pro style and use libs like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)
8. *I have just recently began programming [...] and the internet* - the internet offers many many how-to's and books and ... 80% provide you with bad practice or outdated information. You only need stackoverflow and php.net for mastering this language.

Comment: Thank you DanFromGermany! I think these links will be usefull!

Can I assume from these answers that this community will not look into questions with this old coding style? 
Cuz i am under the impression that I must now re-write my whole form just to be able to make things work or to ask for help..

Comment: You should rewrite the code that recieves the form values. 1. get the `$_POST` variables and check for their contents 2. instance a database object (pdo/mysqli) 3. prepare and insert into the db. The more precize and specific a question is, the more likely you well get an accurate answer. Questions for plain reviewing or rewriting will often get downvoted or even closed. You should really go for the basics to get more confident with the syntax.

Comment: For the Record,
I notice many replies on questions (also from other ppl's questions) that they answer that the codes used are either outdated or simply wrong choice of codes to perform certain actions.

I wonder: If certain apps and programs were written long before these changes and updates in script language came, Where does a beginner in porgramming find the old scripting ways to be able to compare with new ones.. And how to keep track with updates and new stuff? I mean in order for a beginner to get familiar and practice, some of the old basic stuff would be needed wouldn't it?

Comment: The code get's easier to maintain simply by using proper objects. If you make your money with PHP, you will get in contact with many sources and you will automatically be up to date. When you visit the links in my answer, you will find this big red warning: "_This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information._"

Comment: Cheers Dan! Thnx a lot for ur time